# Prove quotient group $G/H$ is an abelian if and only if $g_1.g_2.g_1^{-1}.g_2^{-1}\in H$ for all $g_1,g_2\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

> Let $H$ be a normal subgroup in a group $\langle G,.\rangle$. Prove that $\langle G/H,\circ\rangle$ is abelian if and only if $g_1.g_2.g_1^{-1}.g_2^{-1}$ is in $H$ for all $g_1$ and $g_2$ in $G$.

I'm not really sure how to prove this at all, could someone please tell, Thanks.

Comment: The subgroup of all such elements of the form $g_{1}g_{2}g_{1}^{-1}g_{2}^{-1}$ is called the commutator subgroup. So just for your info....$G/H$ is abelian iff the commutator subgroup is inside $H$.

Comment: oh okay thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take a quotient $G/H$ we know that two equivalence classes $g_1H$ and $g_2H$ are the same ($g_1H = g_2H$) iff $g_1g_2^{-1} \in H$. This is the definition of the equivalence relation used to define the quotient.

Now we know that $G/H$ is abelian iff $g_1H \circ g_2H = g_2H \circ g_1H$ for all $g_1, g_2 \in G$. By definition of the multiplication in the quotient this is equivalent to $g_1g_2H = g_2g_1H$ for all $g_1, g_2 \in G$. But the last statement is by definition of the equivalence relation equivalent to $g_1g_2(g_2g_1)^{-1} = g_1g_2g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1} \in H$.